# Apply all year's dates as keys into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with 364 values. Each value of the array represents a status of each day of the year.

The array looks like this:

```
array([0]=>'something',
      [1]=>'something_else'
      ....
      [364]=> 'the_end_of the year')
```

What  i want to do is to replace all the `array keys` with the dates of the year. Something that looks like this:

```
array([2015-01-01]=>'something',
      [2015-01-02]=>'something_else'
      ....
      [2015-12-31]=> 'the_end_of the year')
```

Comment: foreach can be your friend

Comment: :) yes i know! but don know how to play with the dates!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok here is an example

```
 <?php
     $new = array();
     for($i=0; $i<365; $i++) {
        $key = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('01.01.2015 +'.$i.' days'));
        $new[$key] = $i;
     }
     var_dump($new);
     die;
```

and in your case

```
  $new = array();
  foreach($array as $i=>$value) {
    $key = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('01.01.2015 +'.$i.' days'));
    $new[$key] = $value;
  }
  var_dump($new);
  die;
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can use something like this.

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    // Start date
    $date = '2015-1-1';
    // End date
    $end_date = '2015-12-31';

    $result = array();
    while (strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
        $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
        $result[$date]="your info";
    }
    echo "<pre>";print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try with -

```
$begin = new DateTime('2015-01-01');
$end = new DateTime('2015-12-31');
$end = $end->modify('+1 day'); 

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
$new = array();
foreach($daterange as $date){
    $new[$date->format("Ymd")] = "Your values";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate thru array and convert current day to a DateTime object using createFromFormat method like this

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('z Y', '110 2015');
```

where 110 is the day of the year and 2015 is year against which to create the date to. From there you should be able to set the keys to whatever format you please.